# c# Fill a listView with data from several Linq queries

Tags: c#, wpf, linq, mvvm

My code checks several comboboxes and refines the result via several queries. 
When I check an "Etablissement" in a combobox, a listView displays the list of agents for that Etablishment. This works perfectly. The problem is when I select two or more, I get no result in the list of agents.

Evertime i check one of the list, i call this :

```
      if (_TousAgents != null && _Agents != null)
            {
                _agents = from agent in _TousAgents //_TousAgents contain a list of all agents indiscriminately
                          where DateFin >= agent.DebutContrat
                            && (agent.FinContrat == null
                            || DateDébut <= agent.FinContrat)
                          select agent;
                if (_SelectedStatut != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_SelectedStatut.IDStatut))
                    _agents = from agent in _agents
                          where agent.Typecontrat == _SelectedStatut.IDStatut
                          select agent;
                if (_SelectedService != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_SelectedService.ID))
                    _agents = from agent in _agents
                              where agent.IDService == _SelectedService.ID
                              select agent;
                if (_SelectedSection != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_SelectedSection.ID))
                    _agents = from agent in _agents
                              where agent.IDSection == _SelectedSection.ID
                              select agent;
                if (_SelectedEmploi != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_SelectedEmploi.IDEmploi))
                    _agents = from agent in _agents
                              where agent.IDEmploi == _SelectedEmploi.IDEmploi
                              select agent;
                if (_SelectedFiliere != null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(_SelectedFiliere.ID))
                    _agents = from agent in _agents
                              where agent.IDFiliere == _SelectedFiliere.ID
                              select agent;

                foreach (Etablissement etb in EtablissementsUtilisateur)
                    if (etb.IsSelected == true)
                    {
                        _agents = from agent in _agents
                                  where agent.IDEtablissement == etb.IDEtablissement
                                  select agent;
                    } //I think this is the problem


                _Agents.Clear();
                foreach (AgentModel ag in _agents.Distinct().OrderBy(a => a.Prenom).OrderBy(a => a.Nom))
                {
                    _Agents.Add(ag);
                }

                if (_Agents != null && _Agents.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(SingleAgentMatricule) && _Agents.SingleOrDefault(ag => ag.Matricule == _SingleAgentMatricule) != null)
                    {
                        _Agents.SingleOrDefault(ag => ag.Matricule == _SingleAgentMatricule).IsSelected = true;
                    }
                    else
                        SelectAllAgents = true;

                }
                RaisePropertyChanged("Agents");

            }
```

WPF side :

```
        <ComboBox Name="CmbEtabTout" 
              ItemsSource="{Binding EtablissementsUtilisateur}"
              Grid.IsSharedSizeScope="True"                 
              Grid.Column="2" 
              Grid.ColumnSpan="3" 
              Grid.Row="2" 
              Height="25" 
              Width="250">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="AgentA" Width="auto" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="5" />
                        <ColumnDefinition SharedSizeGroup="AgentB" Width="auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" Command="{Binding DataContext.UpdateListeAgentMulti, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" Grid.Column="0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IdEtablissement}" Grid.Column="1"/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Nom}" Grid.Column="3"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>

       <ListView x:Name="LVAgent"
        ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled" 
        ItemsSource="{Binding Agents}" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Margin="150,0,42,0" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="4" Grid.RowSpan="5" >
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn>
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected}" 
                                              Command="{Binding DataContext.SelectAgentCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=Window}}"
                                              CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding SelectAllAgents}"
                        IsEnabled="True"/>
                </GridViewColumn>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Matricule"
                    Width="110" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Matricule}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Nom" 
                    Width="120"
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Nom}"/>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Prénom" 
                    Width="120" 
                    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Prenom}"/>

            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
```

Exemple of results, with 1 check :

[image]

Everything works.

With 2 or more :

[image]

I'm suppose to fill the ListView with agents from Demo + Demo2018;

Comment: Put a break points into the code and check if you are getting into more than one If statement.  The code looks like you are getting into every IF statement and then only returning the last IF.

Comment: That's ok, i get every "if" statements

Comment: The should you be adding each response to the _agent instead of overwriting the old data?  What happens if two IFs return the same _agent so you have duplicates?

Comment: At the end i use a distinct before add them to the list. And each if = a combobox, i sort agent

Comment: Yes that will work as long as you are adding to the _agent instead of what you are doing now is only ending up with one set of selections.

Answer (score 0):

I think your linq query is wrong because you are asign it everytime you loop in the foreach. 
Maybe you need something like this

```
     _agents = _agents.Where(x=> p = EtablissementsUtilisateur.Where(y=> y.IsSelected == true).Contains(x));
```

Comment: EtablissementUtilisateur is an obervable collection and does not contain a "Contains" definition but i'll try to check this way !